# Subgroup of multiplicative group of nonzero real numbers $\Bbb R^*$ with index $2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $\mathbb{R}^*$ denote the multiplicative group of nonzero real numbers. Is there a subgroup of $\mathbb{R}^*$ with index $2$?

Comment: what are your thoughts on this?

Comment: Well, index 2 means the subgroup is "half" the group. How can you split $\mathbb R^\times$ into two halves?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Show that the [signum function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function) $\operatorname{sgn}$ is a homomorphism from $\Bbb R^*$ onto the multiplicative group $\{-1, 1\}$. The kernel of this homomorphism has index $2$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{\mathbb R^*}{\mathbb R^*_{>0}}\cong\mathbb Z_2\cong\frac{\mathbb Q^*}{\mathbb Q^*_{>0}}$$

Comment: "Less words, more ideas" .. that's algebra!!